# Proof by induction on multiple variables

Tags: inequality, induction

I have the following term to prove by induction:
$$
 \sum_{i=0}^m C(n,i)\le n^m+1
$$

I know that base case for this is n = 1 and m = 0. However, I am not sure how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 4):

It's trivial that the inequality holds for $ m=0,1 $. Now, suppose that we have shown that it's true when $ m=k \ge 1 $. Thus, $$ \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k}{\binom{n}{i}} \le n^k+1 $$ If we can prove that $ \binom{n}{k+1} \le n^{k+1}-n^{k} $, then we're done. Indeed, $$ n^{k+1}-n^{k}=\left(n-1\right)n^k \ge \left(n-1\right)\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k}{\binom{n}{i}}-1\right) > \left(n-1\right)\binom{n}{k}>\binom{n}{k+1} $$
as desired. Note that the equality occurs when $ m=1 $.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I still don't understand how proving C(n, k+1) <= (n^k+1)-(n^k) can solve the problem here though.. firstly, how do you get that term by replacing k with k+1? and then, what happens to the summation? Could please elaborate on that? :)